# JS function create and push into array - only first element is NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, push, nan

```
var tipsArray = [];
var finalBillArray = [];
var tip;
var finalBill;

function calculator(bill) {
    finalBill = tip + bill;

    if (bill < 50) {
        tip = bill * 0.2;
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
        tip = bill * 0.15;
    } else {
        tip = bill * 0.1;
    }

    tipsArray.push(tip);
    finalBillArray.push(finalBill);

    }

calculator(124);
calculator(48);
calculator(268);

console.log(tipsArray);
console.log(finalBillArray);
```

I'm trying to solve one of the tasks on UDEMY course. And can't understand, why only first element in finalBillArray is NaN, but the others looks good.

Comment: variable tip is undefined, adding undefined to a number results in NaN. To fix it initialize the tip variable with 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, `tip` is not assigned to until the `if (bill...` tests inside `calculator`, *below* the assignment to `finalBill`. Assign to `finalBill` *after* creating the `tip` instead, which will not only result in no `NaN`s, but will also give you *accurate* results (your current tips for each bill are being calculated based on the tip of the *previous* bill, not the current bill):

```js
var tipsArray = [];
var finalBillArray = [];

function calculator(bill) {

  var tip;
  var finalBill;
  if (bill < 50) {
    tip = bill * 0.2;
  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
    tip = bill * 0.15;
  } else {
    tip = bill * 0.1;
  }

  tipsArray.push(tip);
  finalBill = tip + bill;
  finalBillArray.push(finalBill);

}

calculator(124);
calculator(48);
calculator(268);

console.log(tipsArray);
console.log(finalBillArray);
```

If you don't like the floating-point numbers there, you can use `Math.round` as well; `Math.round(tip * 100) / 100;` will round to 2 decimal places. (If you don't need a number, you can use `toFixed(2)` instead, which is easier)

```js
var tipsArray = [];
var finalBillArray = [];

function calculator(bill) {

  var tip;
  var finalBill;
  if (bill < 50) {
    tip = bill * 0.2;
  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
    tip = bill * 0.15;
  } else {
    tip = bill * 0.1;
  }
  tip = Math.round(tip * 100) / 100;

  tipsArray.push(tip);
  finalBill = tip + bill;
  finalBillArray.push(finalBill);

}

calculator(124);
calculator(48);
calculator(268);

console.log(tipsArray);
console.log(finalBillArray);
```

Comment: Where defined that you should reset `tip` on each calculation?

Comment: In the `if(bill` conditions, `tip` is necessarily reassigned no matter which path is taken.

Comment: I sure you should make `var tip` outside the calculator scope

Comment: No, it's definitely better to keep variables confined to as small a scope as possible. `tip` is not used outside of the `calculator`, so `tip` should be defined inside `calculator`, not outside.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your `tip` variable is not initialized when you call the function in other words it's `undefined`, so when you call :

```
finalBill = tip + bill;
```

It will return `NaN` because, `undefined+bill` is not a valid `Number`.

**Solution:**

You just need to put the line `finalBill = tip + bill;` after your `if` block, so the `tip` variable can be correctly be initialized.

```
if (bill < 50) {
    tip = bill * 0.2;
} else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
    tip = bill * 0.15;
} else {
    tip = bill * 0.1;
}
finalBill = tip + bill;
```

**Demo:**

```js
var tipsArray = [];
var finalBillArray = [];
var tip;
var finalBill;

function calculator(bill) {

    if (bill < 50) {
        tip = bill * 0.2;
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
        tip = bill * 0.15;
    } else {
        tip = bill * 0.1;
    }
    finalBill = tip + bill;

    tipsArray.push(tip);
    finalBillArray.push(finalBill);

    }

calculator(124);
calculator(48);
calculator(268);

console.log(tipsArray);
console.log(finalBillArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tip should be used only after it calculated / initialize .

```
finalBill = tip + bill;
```

You're using tip without initializing it , therefore - `NUM + NAN = NAN`

```
function calculator(bill) {
    if (bill < 50) {
        tip = bill * 0.2;
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
        tip = bill * 0.15;
    } else {
       tip = bill * 0.1;
    }
    finalBill = tip + bill;
    tipsArray.push(tip);
    finalBillArray.push(finalBill);

    }
```

Comment: I can say the same about your code. It is logically wrong because it change the initial author's logic.

Comment: Think about it, when you go to a restaurant, you pay the tip according to the last visit ?

Answer (score -2):

There is only one change: `var tip = 0;`

```js
var tipsArray = [];
var finalBillArray = [];
var tip = 0;
var finalBill;

function calculator(bill) {
    finalBill = tip + bill;

    if (bill < 50) {
        tip = bill * 0.2;
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
        tip = bill * 0.15;
    } else {
        tip = bill * 0.1;
    }

    tipsArray.push(tip);
    finalBillArray.push(finalBill);

    }

calculator(124);
calculator(48);
calculator(268);

console.log(tipsArray);
console.log(finalBillArray);
```

Comment: Why? There isn't any description @sagi

Comment: Think about it, when you go to a restaurant, you pay the tip according to the last visit ?

Comment: In which country?

Comment: In every country

Comment: Had you visited all countries to claim it? I am talking serious now. I was had to collect my tip when I visited a restaurant. I am not joking.

Comment: No, but I also can claim that there aren't any horses with wings in china although I wasn't there.

Comment: Horses with wings is not collecting a tip

Comment: And tip is calculated based on the **current** check . Regardless the fact that there are countries that doesn't leave tip, no body leaves it for and old check.

Comment: I can explain why. I hadn't any cash to pay a tip, but I wanted to pay cause of excellent service. Then I told to officiant that I would pay a collected tip at the end of a month. It is the real truly situation. (in Russia we pay with card but tips we pay with cash)

Comment: No man. It is not my downvote. And you are much wrong than me

Comment: Keep arguing, and you can continue downvoting , but this won't make you right.

Comment: Seems like people agree with me.

Comment: People give stars to Worpress on the GitHub. It means nothing. You are just looking at the situation only from your point of view. Try to think a bit wider.

Comment: The thing is that author didn't give us a condition for this task. And you had imagine a condition which would be correct for you. But you didn't think about there are many different people and many different laws and so on... Ask all your friends to downvote me and continue to use Worpress only when I will use some brave and modern solutions. Good luck man! ))